# How to log uncaught exceptions in Akka actors?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

We've been having a difficult time detecting and investigating errors in our Akka actors within a Play 2.0.4 application.

How does one get *all* uncaught exceptions in the Akka actors to be logged with useful stacktraces?

The best we've been able to do thus far is to add the following to `application.conf`:

```
logger.akka=DEBUG

akka {
    loglevel = DEBUG
    stdout-loglevel = DEBUG
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    actor {
        debug {
            receive = on
            autoreceive = on
            fsm = on
            lifecycle = on
            unhandled = on
            event-stream = on
            router-misconfiguration = on
        }
    }
}
```

However, given the following actor:

```
class ThrowingActor{
  def receive = {
    case _ => {
      throw new Exception("--------------ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF------------------")
    }
  }
}
```

All that we see getting logged is:

```
[DEBUG] [03/06/2013 16:15:44.311] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] [Future] --------------ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF------------------
```

Can anyone help us get informative stacktraces across all our actors, when there is an uncaught exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange. It should log all exceptions by default.

Comment: Check your logger (log4j/logback/etc) configuration.  Akka will log the exceptions at ERROR level with stack trace.

Comment: You are using configuration settings corresponding to 2.2-M1 or master, does that correspond to your JARs?

Answer (score 7):

If you can't find out of the box handling in Akka, then you can create a simple trait to mix into your actors like so:

```
import akka.actor._

trait UnhandledExceptionLogging{
  self: Actor with ActorLogging =>

  override def preRestart(reason:Throwable, message:Option[Any]){
    super.preRestart(reason, message)
    log.error(reason, "Unhandled exception for message: {}", message)
  }
}

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with UnhandledExceptionLogging{
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      throw new Exception("blah blah")
  }
}
```

Pre-restart will be called when an uncaught exception has occurred and the actor is about to be restarted.  Seems like a good place to hook into your own more detailed logging.  As a bonus, the received message that caused the failure is available for additional context within the log.

You could also refactor this code a little to set up the trait to be stackable in case you have other actors that were already overriding `preRestart`

Comment: You'll probably want to add a call to super.preRestart(reason, message), or else your Actor's postStop method won't be called.

Comment: @user2089674, good point.  I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: The trait does not compile. Compiler says that super.preRestart cannot be called.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the slf4j logger the logging config of Akka is no longer used. Depending on your logging framework and setup, you might have to:

- change logback.xml, logback.groovy or logback-test.xml
- change log4j.xml or log4j.properties
- add a logback or log4j jar on your classpath

Usually when the system spins up it prints some details about the logging framework (particularly if it's misconfigured). There might be many causes, but you're very likely looking in the wrong config file.